# How do I post metadata for a specific event to EventStore?

Tags: eventstoredb

We have metadata associated directly with our events, so I modelled the data in line with the described json blob from EventStore:

```
{
  "eventId": "47b9cc67-ebf5-4990-b95d-ef23e45ee520",
  "eventType": "CreateBadger",
  "data": {
    "badger": "mushroom",
    "mushroom": "badger"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "tenantId": "5af53996-0233-4ffd-b71d-f750d12965d6",
    "subscriptionId": "b6331660-22f7-4c7a-a349-8061c91973cd",
    "userId": "73fccf47-5de0-4eb3-a925-7bbbe1790a35"
  }
}
```

Even though this is the described format, when I try and batch add events to EventStore I get a `400 Write request body invalid.` response.

Looking at single events I can see that I clearly can't add metadata that way.

The question is simple, How do I post metadata for a specific event to EventStore?

I need an atomic commit so to speak, so I was expecting to add the metadata into the body.

The reasoning is that I want to be able to filter a stream based on the values in the metadata to allow a multitenancy approach. (Is that even possible?)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work if you set the `Content-Type` header of your request to `application/vnd.eventstore.events+json`.

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied, I am sick. I'll respond when I've tried it out at work. Thanks for your suggestion though!